# Как из html объекта получить объект jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

К примеру, есть у меня некоторый селектор:

```
$(".external_network_id").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).css('margin'));        
});
```

Я могу изменить его стили при помощи метода `.css` . Но если я передам его в некую функцию

```
$(".external_network_id").each(function(){
    myfunc($(this));
});
```

где

```
function myfunc(object){
    console.log(object.style.margin); //сработает корректно
    console.log(object.css('margin'));  //выведет ошибку
}
```

то я не смогу использовать методы jQuery и придётся довольствоваться JavaScript. Какие преобразования можно сделать, чтобы работать с jQuery внутри функции?

Добавлю пример из проекта, в предыдущем ошибка происходит в строке `console.log(object.style.margin);`
Вот код:

```
$("body .equipment").each(function(){
                    findNetwork($(this));  
            });

function findNetwork(object){
 var id_list = object.find(".network_id");

        $(".room").find(".network .network_id").each(function(){
            var net_in_room = $(this);

            $.each(id_list, function(index, id){
                if (net_in_room.text() == id.textContent){

                    setRoom(net_in_room.closest(".room"), id.closest(".equipment"));

                }
            });
        });

function setRoom(room, object){

        var obj_y = Number(object.style.marginLeft.slice(0, -2));
        var obj_x = Number(object.style.marginTop.slice(0, -2)); //при попытке использовать .css("margin-left") вместо style.marginTop.slice происходит ошибка.
        var obj_width = object.width(); //ошибка происходит конкретно в этой строке
        var obj_height = object.height();


    }
```

Comment: конкретно в приведенном примере ошибка будет в строке _object.style.margin_ так как метод find - возвращает jQuery объект.

Comment: В приведенном коде ошибка все еще будет в строке `console.log(object.style.margin)` так как у jQuery объекта нет свойства `style`. Единственный вариант почему это может сработать - в функцию передается html-элемент. то есть вызов не `myfunc($(this))`, а `myfunc(this)`

Comment: Вы правы, я привёл неудачный пример, он не отображает происходящую ошибку. Исходный пример не стал удалять, добавил лишь пример из настоящего проекта.

Comment: Не. так не пойдет. Добавленный кусок **ничем** не отличается от того, что уже был. Сделай [mcve], по примеру того, что есть в ответе. Чтобы можно было запустить и посмотреть, что действительно выполняется именно так как ты говоришь. Пока же ничего не ясно, не исключено, что у тебя есть еще несколько мест. в которых ты вызываешь _setRoom_ передавая туда нативные html-элементы а не jQuery объекты

Comment: Постарался оставить ключевые моменты связанные с изменениями объектов. Стоит ли добавить html?

Comment: Я нашел твою ошибку :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое поведение характерно при передаче в функцию HTML-элемента, а не jQuery-объекта.

Ошибка заключается в следующих строках

```
$.each(id_list, function(index, id){
    if (net_in_room.text() == id.textContent){

        setRoom(net_in_room.closest(".room"), id.closest(".equipment"));

    }
});
```

Перебирая коллекцию элементов `id_list` в функции-коллбэке в параметре `id` получаем соответствующий HTMLElement, а не jQuery-объект.

В итоге вместо [jQuery функции closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) вызывается [Element.closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), которая так же возвращает HTMLElement.

В качестве решения можно создать jQuery-объект из элемента `id`

```
$.each(id_list, function(index, id){
    var $id = $(id);
    if (net_in_room.text() == $id.text()){
        setRoom(net_in_room.closest(".room"), $id.closest(".equipment"));
    }
});
```

Либо всегда создавать jQuery-объекты *внутри* функции `setRoom`

```
function setRoom(room, object){
    var $room = $(room);// чтобы заранее исключить ситуацию, что в первом параметре так же будет передан не jQuery объект
    var $object = $(object);
    ...
    var obj_width = $object.width(); // работает
    var obj_height = $object.height(); 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробное объяснение. Теперь буду двигаться дальше.

Answer (score 0):

А вы пробовали?

```js
function myfunc(object){
    console.log(object.css('margin'));  
}

myfunc($(".external_network_id"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="external_network_id"></div>
```

Ошибка, конечно, выводится, но только потому, что вы указали `margin` без кавычек, что заставляет интерперетатор думать, что это неинициализированная переменная.

Comment: Я этот пример прямо сходу придумал, сейчас немного подправлю. Но ваш пример всё равно в этом случае не сработает, увы.

Comment: А вы нажмите `Выполнить код`, чтобы посмотреть сработает или нет.

Comment: @ЕвгенийВасильев, сделай сниппет, аналогичный сниппету в ответе, но который бы воспроизвел твою ошибку

Comment: Ещё раз изменю исходный текст. И да, ваш пример действительно  работает.

Comment: @ЕвгенийВасильев, все зависит от того **что** ты передаешь в свою функцию и судя по всему ты передашь не jQuery объект как пишешь в вопросе, а просто HTMLElement.

Comment: Возможно. В таком случае я не совсем понимаю как в функцию передать именно объект jQuery, а не HTML. Буду признателен, если приведёте пример (возможно абстрактный).

Comment: @ЕвгенийВасильев, прежде чем решать проблему ее желательно локализовать. В качеств костыля можно просто принудительно внутри функции создавать jQuery-объект `$(object)` и т.д. но лучше просто найти место где именно происходит ошибка